# How to override markup in my .theme file?

Tags: theming, 8, hooks

Below is markup from `SearchController.php` file. I want to change the "**Search results**" from my search page and also markup.

*File : \core\modules\search\src\Controller\SearchController.php*

```
if (count($results)) {
  $build['search_results_title'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<h2>' . $this->t('Search results') . '</h2>',
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no way to fix this markup in *theme* file. In case you simply need to change spelling I suggest using string overrides as it is described in *settings.php* file.

```
$settings['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = [ 
  'Search results' => 'New text',
];
```

Comment: Where i have to write this function??? In which hook function??

Comment: So, i have to change in setting.php file. Is there any other way to do this??

Comment: Other way could be using [Sting overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module but unfortunately it is not ported to Drupal 8 yet.